# Remove words until a specific character is reached

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python and am having difficulties to remove words in a string

```
9 - Saturday, 19 May 2012
```

above is my string  I would like to remove all string to

```
19 May 2012
```

so I could easily convert it to sql date

here is the could that I tried

```
new_s = re.sub(',', '', '9 - Saturday, 19 May 2012')
```

But it only remove the "," in the String. Any help?

Comment: `new_s = re.sub('[^,]*, ', '', '9 - Saturday, 19 May 2012')`

Comment: In the future, don't use snippets for languages other than html, js, or css, they do not run.

Comment: Will you ever have strings with more than 1 date that you need?

Comment: Split on comma and keep only the 2nd half? Why use regex?

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.split(',')` 
and  you will get

```
['9 - Saturday', '19 May 2012']
```

Comment: Shouldn't use `string` as a variable name, in some versions of python its the name of a builtin module.

Comment: I use string just for clarify the string is a string, not anything else

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `.*` (matching any number of chars) before the `,` (and a space after it which you probably also want to remove:

```
>>> new_s = re.sub('.*, ', '', '9 - Saturday, 19 May 2012')
>>> new_s
'19 May 2012'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is matching a single comma only hence that is the only thing it removes.

You may use a **[negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)** i.e. `[^,]*` to match everything until you match a comma and then match comma and trailing whitespace to remove it like this:

```
>>> print re.sub('[^,]*, *', '', '9 - Saturday, 19 May 2012')
19 May 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is great, but for this you could also use `.split()`

```
test_string = "9 - Saturday, 19 May 2012"
splt_string = test_string.split(",")
out_String = splt_string[1]

print(out_String)
```

Outputs:

```
 19 May 2012
```

If the leading `' '` is a propblem, you can remedy this with `out_String.lstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
a = "9 - Saturday, 19 May 2012"
f = a.find("19 May 2012")
b = a[f:]
print(b)
```